# file_get_contents() converts UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents, iso-8859-1

I am trying to get search results from [yahoo.com](http://yahoo.com).

**But** file_get_contents() converts UTF-8 charset (charset, that yahoo uses) content to ISO-8859-1.

Try:

```
$filename = "http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7lpgGp9NTSYAiQBXNyoA?p=naj%C5%A1%C5%A5astnej%C5%A1%C3%AD&fr2=sb-top&fr=yfp-t-701&type_param=&rd=pref";

echo file_get_contents($filename);
```

Scripts as

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

or

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

or

```
$er = mb_convert_encoding($filename , 'UTF-8');
```

or

```
$s2 = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8",$filename );
```

or

```
echo utf8_encode(file_get_contents($filename));
```

NOT help, because after getting web content speciall characters as š ť ž are replaced with question marks ???

I would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: **file_get_contents() doesn't convert anything**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a [content negotiation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-12) problem as `file_get_contents` probably sends a request that only accepts ISO 8859-1 as character encoding.

You can create a custom [stream context](http://php.net/stream.contexts) for `file_get_contents` using [`stream_context_create`](http://php.net/stream_context_create) that explicitly states that you accept UTF-8:

```
$opts = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$filename = "http://search.yahoo.com/search;_ylt=A0oG7lpgGp9NTSYAiQBXNyoA?p=naj%C5%A1%C5%A5astnej%C5%A1%C3%AD&fr2=sb-top&fr=yfp-t-701&type_param=&rd=pref";
echo file_get_contents($filename, false, $context);
```

Comment: Funny thing, I tried `Accept-Charset=utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7`, but doesn't work :)

Comment: @webarto: The value `utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7` is like `utf-8,*` and would accept any character encoding equally.

Comment: Nice one Gumbo! I was struggling with umlauts in the url (München) - this solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

file_get_contents should *not* change the charset. The data is pulled in as a binary string.

When checking out the url you provided, this is the header it provides:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

Also, in the body:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
```

Also, you can't convert UTF-8 losslessly convert to ISO-8859-1 and get the characters back when going back to UTF-8. UTF-8 / unicode supports many many more characters, so the characters are lost in the first step.

In the browser this is not the case, so perhaps you just need to provide a correct Accept-Encoding header to instruct yahoo's system you can accept UTF-8.

Comment: How did you find out `Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1` and `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">`

When I look in source code of that page I see `<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

Comment: It serves different encoding based on your location, you could try fetching page using Russian proxy servers.

Answer (score 1):

```
$s2 = iconv("ISO-8859-1","UTF-8//TRANSLIT//IGNORE",$filename );
```

Better solution...

```
function curl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 1);
    return curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}

echo curl($filename);
```

Comment: Result is: The document has moved here.

Comment: @vladinko0, I think you need to set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, I've updated my answer, try again.

Comment: Now it loads the page, but with the same result as with file_get_contents() it means with question marks. Charset is also converted to ISO-8859-1.

Comment: It seems that yahoo.com is serving different pages (charsets) depending on your IP (country). I changed your URL to `http://ru.search.yahoo.com` but it doesn't work. Maybe you can achieve something with accept charset headers,refuse ISO-8859-1...

Answer (score 1):

For anyone investigating on this:

The time I spent on encoding issues taught me that rarely php functions "magically" change the encoding of strings. (One of these rare examples is :

```
exec( $command, $output, $returnVal )
```

Please note also that the working header set is as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

and not:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

As I had a similar issue as the one you describe, it was enough to set the headers properly.

Hope this helps!