# file_get_contents show characters of utf-8 like question marks

Tags: php, utf-8, file-get-contents

```
$str = "https://www.google.com/search?q=sd";
echo file_get_contents($str);
```

I'm try to load page from google with the function file_get_contents, but the output of chracters of utf-8 showing like question mark.

I've tried all the possibilities introduced here:
[file_get_contents() converts UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600371/file-get-contents-converts-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1)
But the problem is still not resolved.

I would appreciate any help very.

**UPDATE:**

I see that the problem exists through Google, other sites content is displayed correctly.

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure - do you send a header that ensures your php script is parsed as UTF-8?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Your very first statement (before sending any html)  should be `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");`

Comment: Thank you, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[php]

```
//charset.php?case=1
//charset.php?case=2
//charset.php?case=3

$case = isset($_GET['case']) ? $_GET['case'] : 1;

if( !in_array($case,range(1,3)) ) $case = 1;


if( $case==1 ) {
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=tis-620"); //http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-utf8.html
    $str = "https://www.google.co.th/search?q=sd";
}

if( $case==2 ) {
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
    $str = "https://www.google.de/search?q=sd";
}   

if( $case==3 ) {
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9");
    $str = "https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=sd";
}


$data = file_get_contents($str);
echo $data;
```

[/php]

as you can see ... the correct charset in php header is the solution

Answer (score 1):

try once this code it worked for me ..

```
    <?php 
$abc = array('http' => array('header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8, *;q=0'));
$some_context = stream_context_create($abc);
$filename = "https://www.google.com/search?q=sd";
echo file_get_contents($filename, false, $some_context);
    ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I tried it again and it did not work for me :(

Comment: response is same ? with special character's like question mark is showing ?