# file_get_contents return strange symbols instead website content

Tags: php, file-get-contents

file_get_contents return strange symbols instead website content

Code `echo file_get_contents('https://olbi.su');`

Output:

> ��}y�Ǒ��$��lcwf쮾��]�X[�--`��������8�U����)%�2�my����:?<�"Ekx ���_a?ɋ_d�G���(-�ə��#22"22223j�ܳ/>�ҿ��s�/���[g7��x$F�9�,�SŞ�Dϰ7K#�.  �S]U�,�o6.��]�uu��V+�...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents() Breaks Up UTF-8 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236668/file-get-contents-breaks-up-utf-8-characters) and [file_get_contents converts utf 8 to iso 8859 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600371/file-get-contents-converts-utf-8-to-iso-8859-1) and [file_get_contents show characters of utf 8 like question marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39290627/file-get-contents-show-characters-of-utf-8-like-question-marks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://olbi.su');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , 'gzip');
$content = curl_exec ($ch);

print_r($content);
```

This will show you the whole page like you expect. Use curl library so you can apply encoding.